# Transfer files from one GCP project to another GCP project programmatically (In Java)

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, transfer

What are all possible options to make files transfer across the projects?

Note: Both projects are in different organization networks.

Comment: Where are the files? on a VM Disk or in a GCS bucket ?

Comment: Where are stored the file? Which service do you use? Which protocol do want/need to use to transfert the files?

Comment: @boredabdel , Files are stored in gcs bucket (let's say under organization A we have one project project1 which have one gcs bucket buck1 where some files are there) and we want to move/copy those files into the destination gcs bucket (let's say under organization B we have one project project2 which have one gcs bucket buck2 where we want to copy files)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to do this:

- The easiest would be to spin up a VM in one of the projects, and use gsutil with a Service Account that has Storage permissions to read and write from both projects (The Service Account itself  could belong to either projects)
- Programmatically you can use the [API](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/create-manage-transfer-program#cloud-to-cloud) to transfer the files
- You can also use the [console](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/create-manage-transfer-console) to create transfer jobs